# About the Euler's Disk

Tags: classical-mechanics, singularities

I'm a physics student who got an interest in Euler's disks. As you may know, an Euler's disk is basically a big fat coin spinning upon a (smooth) surface. As the disk loses energy due to friction with air and with the surface itself, its precession frequency increases (theoretically diverging without bounds) until it stops. It's a so-called finite time singularity.

See this video for an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3o0R2hStiY&t=121s&ab_channel=AltoonaYourPiano

The disk has been extensively treated both theoretically and experimentally, and the literature is abundant. For a good example of the experimental treatment, see: https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/ast/42/4/42_E2081/_pdf/-char/en

Note that in the paper I linked above, the authors acquire the audio signal with very basic equipment (an Iphone 7), and do the spectral analysis using an app. They clearly see, in the spectrogram, the fast sweep that the disk's precession frequency performs. They report "from 70 Hz to 220 Hz in the last seconds" and they also attach the spectrogram.

Getting to my questions, I tried to acquire both the audio signal and the mechanical-vibrational signal, getting inconsistent results in both cases. To be more specific...:

1. I tried to acquire the audio signals from multiple disk/surface systems made of various materials, including ones very similar to the canonical toy (some of mine spin for even longer times). I used various microphones and apps (including the one they use..) but all I can get is the high-frequency sound generated by the friction. Still, I hear the precession frequency quite neatly. My conjecture is that the high-pitched noise generated by the friction is modulated by the precession (the disk acts as an acoustic reflector, I gather..). But WHY don't my microphones get the precession??
2. I tried to acquire the signal by putting an accelerometer upon the surface (it's a bit difficult to put it on the disk directly without disturbing the disk itself). Note that the surface is quite flexible and it is suspended, as you may see in the video above.
   My accelerometer has a sampling rate of ~400Hz (so we get Nyquist at half that). Nonetheless, I observe a signal going from ~15Hz at the start, up to 35-40 Hz just before the singularity.

This is not in accordance with what I hear and with what the guys above measured. Indeed, the first precessions of the disk are clearly heard at not much more that 2 or 3 Hz (see the video).
Furthermore, the last precessions, just before the singularity, are clearly heard at a much higher frequency than 40 Hz, and this is confirmed once again by the findings in the paper above.

I was thinking that maybe the surface acts as a "filter", injecting its own normal modes of oscillation. Indeed, look at the video between ~1:30 and 1:50...
By carefully observing the surface, you can clearly see how strangely the surface vibrates..

Comment: My first thought about sound recording is "where are you putting the microphone?" This can have a huge impact on what sounds you're picking up, especially if the microphone is resting on the table. I suggest holding your phone as the lads did in figure 1.a) and trying that, if you haven't done so already. 


As for the accelerometer, the particular way the disk rotates might make it difficult or impossible to measure the angular velocity of the contact point (big omega in the paper) through any linear acceleration in the object. If you have a gyroscope as they used in the paper, try that.

Comment: @jstl Thanks for your reply. About the audio part, I tried placing the mic(s) on the table, holding them as they do, and even have them suspended with a wire. No effect. About the vibrational part, would you please elaborate about why it'd be difficult to measure Omega by evaluating the vertical linear acceleration of the surface? Thanks! :)

Comment: I suppose the vertical acceleration will work fine for the end of the rotations, when the disk is close to horizontal (which is where you're having problems). At the beginning, though, you'll encounter problems with there being very little vertical motion of any point in the disk. 


As for your original question, I suggest giving some more detail (photos, perhaps) of your measurement process and the data that result from those measurements, so that readers might be able to find what's going wrong in your experiment.

Comment: Have you tried a larger Euler's disk? that might be easier to use the accelerometer with. Any reasonably heavy and round object will do, and a bigger one will be less disturbed by the accelerometer.

Comment: Copy that. I'll gather some more material and post it. Thanks!